Can't access variables imported in html module script in other non-modules (FaunaDB imported)
Been trying to use FaunaDB in my website, and i cant seem to figure out much, ChatGPT has helped me for the most part but it can't help here for some reason... heres my current code:


const client = new Client({
secret: '...nope i am not gonna let someone have my key...',
});

async function RunQ(query) {
try {
    // Run the query
    const result = await client.query(query);
    return JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
} catch (error) {
    // Handle errors
    return new Error(error.message);
}
}

// here us an example function
async function CreateUser() {
const query = fql`
users.createData({
email: 'me@gmail.com',
pass: 'pass1',
totals: {
}
})
`;
await RunQ(query);
}
<script type="module">import{Client,fql}from'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fauna@latest/dist/browser/index.js';console.log(fql ? 'MODULE LOADED' : 'FAILED TO LOAD MODULE')</script>
<script src="./main.js"></script>



It logs 'MODULE LOADED', but when i run CreateUser() it errors that 'fql not found'.
Does this have to do with the fact that it is a module? I don't know what's wrong and I've been trying to fix it for a while now, so thanks in advance!

Possibly a duplicate of: How to use an exported function in a script tag?
You should be sure to export CreateUser from your script.
export async function CreateUser() { /* ... */ }

Then tag your script as type="module", and then also be sure to import CreateUser where you need it. The other topic I linked to above has more examples.
Additional references:

export docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export
import docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import


As an aside, I note you storing a password field for your user. Please do not ever store plain passwords in a database.
Fauna provides the built-in Credential collection, which automatically hashes a provided password and stores that. You can then use the .login() method to generate a Fauna Token for your user, or you can use .verify() just to check the password.
Checkout the documentation for more information on creating and managing tokens: https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/learn/security/tokens/#create-manage-tokens
